# Maven Archetype: Sub-package names

Tags: java, maven, archetypes

I am creating a maven archetype.

I know if I put my `src/main/java/App.java` class in there, I can get the package name with:

```
package $package;
```

But now I want to add a class like this: `src/main/java/service/MyService.java`

How do I inject the proper package in there?

```
$package
```

Gives me the root package.  And `$package.service` just resolves as a literal.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
${package}.service
```

Comment: This would give me the correct package name in the .java file but the subfolder isn't created.  In this example, I wouldn't get the service folder.

Comment: @AR3Y35 The MyService file has to be in the `src/main/java/service/MyService.java` folder to create the subfolder and needs this package declaration: `package ${package}.service;`

Answer (score 0):

As @snovawinter proposed, use Maven property notation.

${x} means Maven property. You already noticed that Maven only works with root package here, and that's (I think) for a reason: archetypes ain't projects, they are project templates. By default: rather small - top level package is the limit.

So, having some subpackages: **put all files in your top directory, and use**

```
package ${package};
```

or

```
package ${package}.subpackage;
```

in them.